# Does Azure Redis Charged for running instance?

Tags: azure-redis-cache

I am using Azure Redis cache and there is no clear documentation of how it is charged. In the portal it specifies that its charged on instance type like c0 to c6 and rates are per hour. If I want to create a redis instance of c6 and do not want to use it for some time or stop it. I do not see any option of stopping it. So will I be charged for until the instance is running or its based on usage i.e. inbound and outbound transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information about pricing for Azure Redis cache: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cache/

The pricing rates are different depending on cache size (C0, C1, C2 etc.) and SKU (Basic, Standard). Basic is a single node solution. Standard is a Primary / Secondary configuration with replication.

The pricing page lists pricing as an hourly rate. Caches are billed on a per-minute basis from the time that a cache is created till the time that a cache is deleted.